# XWalkView change inputType method

Tags: android

In our android app we use `XWalkView` instead of standard `WebView` for better performance.

I'm looking for a way how to show text tips on keyboard when user input, which is disabled by default in `XWalk`, but presented in standard `WebView`. 
And second problem, when using `XWalk`, keyboard has pressed shift by default.

Is there any way to show keyboard without `shift` and with tips like in `WebView`?
Sorry for my weak English.

Comment: Have you tried using java script like <input type="text" style="text-transform:lowercase;" on keyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();">

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change behavior of web part, only from android side, thats why, I haven't.